# how to delete the key from dict when concat data frames in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to join pandas dataframes that are stored in dictionary. 
For example:
in the dic, for each key, it has a data frame as corresponding value

this is my code, but it has a little bit difference from my goal:

pd.concat(dic, axis = 1)

Appreciate!

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me to delete the key from the new dataframe? 
I am using python

Comment: If you could provide some runnable code, it would help clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df = pd.concat(dic, axis = 1)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df)
     colorApple colorYellow
Date                       
1/3        red1        red2
3/5     yellow1     yellow2
```